# Apche spark-1.3.1, I am getting exception ClassNotFoundException while UDTF lateral view used

Tags: apache-spark

While executing hive query with UDTF using apache spark 1.3.1 then alias name does not take
And If i use UDTF using lateral veiw then i got class not found for Custom UDTF class.

Answer (score 0):

This mentioned issue was reported under spark 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.1 and 1.3.0, it has been resolved and will be available with spark 1.4.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/SPARK-4811